# Copy files from my android phone to my PC via batch file

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I need to create a batch file that can copy a log file to a PC.  The batch file I created  doesn't work.  When I run all the commands manually it works however when putting into a script it hangs.  Here are the individual commands:

```
adb shell
run-as com.program
cat /data/data/com.program/files/logfile.log > /sdcard/logfile.log
exit (leave shell)
adb pull /sdcard/logfile.log c:\logs\logfile.log
```

Here is what I have that doesn't work:

```
@echo off
cls
Echo Copying Log files to SD Card:
echo ------------------------------
echo.
@adb shell run-as com.xerox
cat /data/data/com.program/files/logfile.log > /sdcard/logfile.log
exit
adb pull /sdcard/logfile.log.0 c:\logs\logfile.log

pause
```

All it does is go into a shell when the "`@adb shell run-as com.program`" command is run and hang there, I can't do anything after that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Try this single line command:

```
$adb shell run-as com.example.name cat /data/data/com.example.name/files/logfile.log > c:\logs\logfile.log
```

Comment: I had to remove the $ from adb and it worked perfectly!  Thanks!

Comment: I added the $ to denote the command prompt. Anyway, if it answers your question, mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `adb shell` that first time, you are no longer in your desktop's console session. You are now in a shell on the phone. So your computer is still waiting for the `adb shell` command to finish before trying to run the `cat` command. As your batch file will then never exit `adb shell`, it hangs.